# How to set swagger UI to be able use Try It Out with Authentication?

Tags: swagger-ui

I am trying ot find a way how to setup properly Swagger UI to be able use **Try It Out** functionality with Authentication. I have API whith Basic HTTP Authentication which is crucial for business.

Unfortunately Swagger UI sends only OPTIONS requests without Basic HTTP header.

I found some articles on internet but almost all are saying that OPTIONS doesn't contain the header.

Is it there any way how to force Swagger UI use POST including the Authorization header instead of OPTIONS without the header?

```
Request URL:https://blabla.blabla.com/rest/blabla/ShipmentRequest
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:001.02.003.004:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Thank you, Reddy

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/cors.md

Comment: I did it. However I just realized that all is working fine from Internet Explorer but not from Chrome and FF. Weird. Usually I have oposite troubles.